# The Control or Control

Tags: articles

I have a debate with a friend about the following sentence.

*We have only one goal - to give you the control of your finances.*

My friend argues that "the" in this sentence is wrong, saying it is unnecessary and therefore wrong.

My argument is that the "the" in this case suggests that you have ALL the control while control without an article could mean that you would only have some of the control.

Another point of discussion is the word "of" in this sentence. He says it should be "over your finances", while I think both work but "of your finances" sounds better.

I hope I've made my case clear. I am not a native Engish speaker, so not sure whether I am in the right place here.

Comment: It's not necessarily "wrong," but it's not at all idiomatic. If you want to say *all the control*, then replace *the* with *complete*.